# C# JSON.NET convention that follows underscore gives me headact

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, jsonparser

I have a post method response json body exactly like this:

```
[{
  "_routeId": "657a2fe455905539f9eed1a5",
  "distance": {
    "text": "859 km",
    "value": 859444
  },
  "duration": {
    "items": {
      "days": 0,
      "hours": 10,
      "minutes": 22,
      "seconds": 31
    },
    "text": "10hr 22min",
    "value": 37351
  }}]
```

So far, I can get duration field with my data transfer model but I couldn't get **_routeId** field.  Here is my dto, I've tried JsonPropertyName already but I have not solved unfortunately.

```
public class DistanceMatrixResponseModel {
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_routeId")]
  public string RouteId { get; set; }

  public RouteDistanceModel Distance { get; set; }

  public RouteDistanceModel Duration { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do?

So far, I have tried to get _ underscore fields with JsonPropertyName. duration fields is okay, but other field which name is _routeId returns null. I couldn't map each other.

Comment: Works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KO1G9E What versions do you use for Framework/NewtonSoft ... ?

Comment: Using the `JsonPropertyName` attribute in `System.Text.Json.Serialization` [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0xgZLS). Can you show an example of how you're creating and using the `DistanceMatrixResponseModel`?

Comment: @Fildor my newtonsoft.json version is 13.0.1

Comment: Tried also in .Net7 / 13.0.1 : https://dotnetfiddle.net/89DYq0 still works. Do you have any non-default options set?

Comment: @Peppermintology I have tried Newtonsoft.. code editor advice that. but your solution, using system.text.json.serialization works. Thanks, grazie!

Comment: @Fildor I have tried both as your answer sir and @Peppermintology. So far it works both. So I can say that there are two options to solve this issue:
 - `using system.text.json.serialization` rather than newtonsoft
 - or using .net7 cause i realized that i was working on .net6.0.3

Comment: If you really need a help you should post all classes and code that you were using. For example I can only an object model, but your json is an array